# why objective-c does not support same method name in difference class?

Tags: objective-c

Here is a code snippet from *Learning objective-c 2.0* 
Full code:

ClassWithFloat.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassWithFloat : NSObject
{
    float value;
}
-(void)setValue:(float)aValue;
@end
```

ClassWithFloat.m

```
#import "ClassWithFloat.h"

@implementation ClassWithFloat
-(void)setValue:(float)aValue
{
    value = aValue;
}
@end
```

ClassWithInt.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassWithInt : NSObject
{
    int value;
}
-(void)setValue:(int)aValue;
@end
```

ClassWithInt.m

```
#import "ClassWithInt.h"

@implementation ClassWithInt
-(void)setValue:(int)aValue
{
    value = aValue;
}
@end
```

main.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ClassWithFloat.h"
#import "ClassWithInt.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        id number = [[ClassWithInt alloc] init];
        [number setValue:3];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

failed to compile, after changing to `ClassWithInt* number` it works.

Error message:

```
/Users/jcyangzh/src/oc/SameName/SameName/main.m:17:9: Multiple methods named 'setValue:' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes
```

But since objective-c is somehow a dynamic programming language, the message call will be translated to native C method call.

`obj_msgSend(number, @selector(setValue:), 3)`

the `obj_msgSend` method find the class structure for the `number` object by `isa` variable.  Which should make no difference between `id` or `ClassWithInt` type.

Why objective-c compiler could not recognize the right method?

*Note*: I am asking this question, because having same method name, but different argument type for **different** class is reasonable to me. But it seems that it is not possible either because the compiler limitation or the language design (do not supporting method overloading etc).

Comment: It compiles for me... obviously not exactly as written, since you use `[number setValue:3]` at the top level.  Could you give an example that you can compile directly?

Comment: @DietrichEpp: First import classWithfloat's header file.

Comment: I put everything in one file.  It still compiles.  What error are you getting?

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Full code included, please recheck.

Comment: @MarkBessey: Full code provided. please re-check.

Comment: WHAT IS THE ERROR MESSAGE???  (Most likely you're getting a warning that the call is ambiguous.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem really is that your object is only typed as id within the lexical scope. 
The compiler doesn't know which method of the same name/selector to use. 
You have multiple classes that have that selector but with different signatures because their arguments are different types. 
You should avoid id in this case
Or typecast your object in the message send brackets to tell the compiler what class's method to use 
Or 
Bracket the same message call repeatedly in a sequence of if ([obj isKindOf: 
checks. (Crazy here)
Or 
Best take a hint from NSNumber class on good method naming conventions and do something like setFloatValue: and setIntValue: which is more readable and clear and helps the compiler a bit.

But any time you have and id type only, you need to be checking if the object isKindOf: or you are asking for trouble.

Comment: It's a very dynamic language but doesn't do type coercion the way a lot of interpreted languages like Ruby will do. And even those cannot always disambiguate method calls all the time

Answer (score 1):

It is **very** *very* ***bad*** to have methods with same name but different signatures. (It is documented somewhere but I can't find now)

The calling conversion between calling `setValue:(float)` is different to `setValue:(int)`, compiler have to generate different binary code.

As you said, it end up with something like

```
obj_msgSend(number, @selector(setValue:), 3)
```

but they are different

```
obj_msgSend(number, @selector(setValue:), (int)3)
obj_msgSend(number, @selector(setValue:), (float)3.0f)
```

Compiler have to decide at compile-time to generate the which version. Because the calling conversion between pass parameter with `int` type and `float` type are different.

Given code

```
ClassWithInt *number = [[ClassWithInt alloc] init];
[number setValue:3];
```

Compile know it need to generate the version with `int` with the help of type information.

but without type information

```
id number = [[ClassWithInt alloc] init];
[number setValue:3]; // is this takes int or float? if it is float then 3 need to be convert to float value first
```

There are two possible way to call it. Compiler can't figure it out without help. Hence the error message.

Comment: In conclusion, it is root cause is C does not support function overloading, since oc is translated to C.

Comment: @Jichao No. ObjC does not need method overloading.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this was "very very bad", it's just something you need to be aware of. In many/most cases, there is no problem with having multiple methods with the same name that take different arguments. You just need to tell the compiler what class you're using when it matters.

Comment: @MarkBessey methods the should have different name if they take different argument. so people can understand the code without guessing. and compiler can compile the correct code without guessing. when compiler did choose the wrong method signature, you will have no idea why the program crashed.

Comment: @BryanChen: But different class happens to have same method signature is un-avoidable.

Comment: @Jichao In term of runtime and code generation, all ObjC object parameter are same. So `setObjectValue:(NSString *)` have same method signature as `setObjectValue:(NSArray *)`. This makes it easier to avoid.